# How to make a touchable notice top bar in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reflection, system-tray

How to make a touchable notice top bar in windows phone ?

I am new to C# and windows phone world.So may be my question has a simple 
way to solve,but I google a lot ,and didn't work out.
    here is my purpose: I have a timer running throughout my app,it request a 
service for notice info every one hour, and show a "notice bar" on the top of 
screen.
    it is easy to get the information ,but when I want to show them to the Page,
here is my problem:

**1.**
I used system tray to show my info.
    It works,but then I found there is no touch or click event for Progress 
Indication bar.
    I even add an event to Touch.FrameReported in App.xaml.cs , but still ,
when i touch the system tray area, the event doesn't fire.

**2.**
Then I want to use a Dynamic way to achieve it: add a text block to the 
current page
    I got the current page handler ,but case I only know the current page 
handler's type is PhoneApplicationPage, I can't get my Root UI element 
(all my page has a root element named "LayoutRoot")
    And when I try to use reflect method to get the "LayoutRoot" property,
the return value is null.

The code looks like this :

```
Type type = PhoneApplicationPageHandler.getType()<
//I checked,the type is my page's type
type.getProperty("LayoutRoot") or type.getField("LayoutRoot")
//they all return null
```

BTW: LayoutRoot is a grid, and it is  described in my page's .xmal file.

Now My option is to make all my page inherit a defalut page ,in this page ,I will 
implement a method to fulfill my second way to simulate a "touchable top bar".

but I think this coding is ugly .

So, can anyone tell me :
1.how to add touch event to a SystemTray 
or 
2.how to get a handler of an ui element which is described in xaml, while I only have a PhoneApplicationPage type handler of that page.

Comment: you may be better off using [toast push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202967%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), rather than emulating it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use 
1) a toast prompt described here http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth 

2)or shell toast described here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae35ca/working-with-toast-notification-in%C2%A0windows-phone-7/ according to what suits your requirement the best. 
3)You may also create a custom control which you may place on the top on your mainPage and handle its tap event accordingly.

Comment: thanks,I used messageBox to accomplish that.   It's ugly,now I am reading the article you mentioned.